# For $k=0,1,...,\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, show that ${n \choose 2}=2{k \choose 2}$+${n-2k \choose 2}+k(2n-3k)$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

for $k=0,1,...,\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, show that ${n \choose 2}=2{k \choose 2}$+${n-2k \choose 2}+k(2n-3k)$.

We're supposed to use graph theory to answer this. I know that ${n \choose 2}$ is the number of edges in a complete graph on n nodes. Somehow the right hand side must also equal this but I don't know how. I don't understand what $k$ is representing here.

Answer (score 2):

To show:
$$\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n-2k}{2}=2\binom{k}{2}+k(2n-3k)$$

$\binom{n}{2}$ is the no. of edges in the complete graph on $n$ vertices.
Remove two sets, $A$ and $B$, of $k$ vertices from the graph and there would only be the $n-2k$ vertices and $\binom{n-2k}{2}$ edges left.

The RHS represents the no. of edges lost in the process. Can you enumerate it in another way?